# Excel button is not disabled even when IsEnabled property is set to false

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid, isenabled

On button click I want the button clicked to be disabled and after executing a process re-enable it.

While it seems quite simple, for a reason the whole process executes successfully but the button is not disabled. It gets disabled on specific occasions and not in the start of the button click.

Below is the XAML code of the button

```xml
<Button 
    x:Name="PreviewReportButton"
    Click="PreviewExcelReportButton_Click"
    Background="{StaticResource ExportExcelButtonColor}"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ExportExcelButtonColor}"
    Focusable="False"
    IsEnabled="False"
    Width="80"
    Height="Auto"
    Margin="450,0,0,0"
    FontSize="9"
    FontWeight="DemiBold"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Grid.Column="3"
    Grid.Row="5"
    Cursor="Hand"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">Button 1</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

The .cs file code in c# VS 2019

```cs
private void PreviewExcelReportButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn_excel = (Button)sender;
    btn_excel.IsEnabled = false;
    //PreviewReportButton.IsEnabled = false; This is the same button as btn_excel (the button I want to click)

    Debug.WriteLine("Button must be disabled");

    try
    {
        //Check if file is open
        int IsMacroFileOpen = CheckFileIsOpen($@"{path}file_1.xlsm");
        int IsReportFileOpen = CheckFileIsOpen($@"{path}file_2.xlsm");
        int IsXLSXFileOpen = CheckFileIsOpen($@"{path}file_3.xlsx");

        Debug.WriteLine(IsMacroFileOpen);
        Debug.WriteLine(IsReportFileOpen);
        Debug.WriteLine(IsXLSXFileOpen);

        if (new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(IsMacroFileOpen) || new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(IsReportFileOpen) || new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(IsXLSXFileOpen))
        {
            btn_excel.IsEnabled = true;
            return;
        }

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

        //Step 1: Create copy of standard report file
        CreateCopyReportServerNameDB($@"{path}file_1.xlsm");

        //Step 2: Run macro
        ExecuteExcelMacro($@"{path}file_2.xlsm");

        //Step 3: Open a copy of the xlsx updated file
        //Approach 1
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        ExcelApp.Visible = true;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add($"{path}file_3.xlsx");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.Effect = new BlurEffect();
        bool? Result = new CustomMessageBox($"Unable to execute Excel button.\nPlease contact application support", "Error produced", MessageType.Error, MessageButtons.Ok).ShowDialog();
        if (Result.Value)
        {
            this.Effect = null;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Effect = null;
            return;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        btn.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Don't pay so much attention on what each method (CreateCopyReportServerNameDB, ExecuteExcelMacro) do because it's not relevant to the question. The whole functionality works. What does not work is the button disable on top of my code. When I click the button, the Cursor changes to *Wait* since I use `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;`. The weird thing is that the button is only disabled when a file is open which is catched by `CheckFileIsOpen` method. If no file is open the button is never disabled. And I am sure that I disable the button only on the top of the class and I renable it only at the end.

Also you will notice that I have put a `Debug.Writeline` to write if the `IsEnabled = false;` successfully executes and indeed the line is written as output. Although the button is never disabled unless a file is open and get caught by the mehtod `CheckFileIsOpen`.

Apologize that I reached the point to post a question for such a "dummy" think because to me it's obvious. But I cannot understand why this is happening to the IsEnabled of the button. Apologize if this is so simple, but I cannot figure out what is happening.

The problem seems to be when I execute the second method `ExecuteExcelMacro`
The code of this method

```cs
public void ExecuteExcelMacro(string sourceFile)
{
    var destinationFile = @"file_1";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(sourceFile);

    string macro = "ThisWorkbook.Run_Code";
    try
    {
        ExcelApp.Run(macro);
        Debug.WriteLine("Macro: " + macro + " executed successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.Effect = new BlurEffect();
        bool? Result = new CustomMessageBox($"Unable to Run Macro: {macro}", "Cannot execute Macro", MessageType.Error, MessageButtons.Ok).ShowDialog();
        if (Result.Value)
        {
            this.Effect = null;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Effect = null;
            return;
        }
        //Debug.WriteLine("Unable to Run Macro: " + macro + " Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }

    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    ExcelApp.Visible = false;

    ExcelWorkBook.SaveAs($@"{path}{destinationFile}", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing);
    ExcelWorkBook.Close(0);
    ExcelApp.Quit();

    if (ExcelWorkBook != null) { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook); }
    if (ExcelApp != null) { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp); }
}
```

Comment: After `btn_excel.IsEnabled = false;` put `Task.Delay(5000);` and tell me what happens ?

Comment: @RaoHammas I already test that because I thought that maybe the execution of the other methods was instant. But again the button won't get disabled

Comment: There must be something else. Because button should be disabled after click. Can you remove all your button extra style and check ? maybe.. You are not noticing it right ?

Comment: @RaoHammas yeah I will try to re-create it step by step. Button extra style meaning the intermediate processes?

Comment: Wait. you have this line `btn_excel.IsEnabled = true;` in your `If` condition this must be executing everytime. And every time this `If` condition would be true and Button gets enabled ..maybe ?

Comment: I hope not because ```int IsMacroFileOpen``` returns 0,1,2...0 is returned when the files are closed so the if statement won't execute.

Comment: Please don't hope. but test it .. put a break point there and see what happens. or for now remove this line from `If` condition. and then check ...

Comment: @RaoHammas The weird thing is that if I open an excel file the button will be disabled and the ```int IsMacroFileOpen``` will return either 1 or 2 and the if statement will re-enable the button so the user can close the excel file first and then re-click the button. But if all of my files are closed the button is never disabled at the start of the process :(

Comment: Have you tried removing that line and checked ? because if that line is not the issue then i'm sure issue is not in this code that you have shared !

Comment: @RaoHammas I am with you but I know that the code posted is the one that only calls the btn.IsEnabled = false. I will keep searching I guess. Thanks for the effort though :).

Comment: I'm just asking have you tried ? removing `btn_excel.IsEnabled = true;` from `If` condition or not ?

Comment: @RaoHammas yeah I tried it and the same result. I will try your recommendation to break it into parts.

Comment: @RaoHammas The problem seems to be when I execute the excel procedures and especially the second one ```ExecuteExcelMacro```

Comment: @RaoHammas pls check my update :)

Comment: No not at all. I see not a single line in second method regarding button. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Also. The code you shared so far have on two possiblities of this problem. No one code execute si fast that you don't notice disabled behavior or that If condition is executing everytime !!! Nothing else seems to be a problem

Comment: @RaoHammas it's really weird to me too. :) Because like you I don't see any problem. Also I dont see any code executing every time. But once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExecuteExcelMacro() method, after creating an instance of ExcelApp
make **`ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating=false; ExcelApp.Calculation=manual; ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts=false;`**.

**Don't made `ExcelApp.Visible=false;`**

And in final block of PreviewExcelReportButton_Click() method, do
**Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;**

Comment: Hello Yuvraj, ty for your answer. I will accept it since it worked as expected :)